# Что обозначает термин "уровень ошибки"?

Tags: dataset

Я новичек в Datascience.

У Википедии на странице с информацией о MNIST есть следущее предложение:

> Производились многочисленные попытки достичь минимальной ошибки после обучения по базе данных MNIST, которые обсуждались в научной литературе. Рекордные результаты указывались в публикациях, посвящённых использованию свёрточных нейронных сетей, уровень ошибки был доведён до 0,23 %

Здесь сказано, уровень ошибки - 0.23 %, это означает, что из 10 000 изображений было верно не распознано только 23, или это сума стоимость всех ошибок(которые участвуют в обратном распространении), которые были сделаны во время тестирования сети на датасете?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я всё-таки понял из бумаги, на которую в Википедии дана ссылка, речь именно о проценте неправильно распознанных изображений после тренировки сети. Поскольку сложность сети довольно небольшая относительно числа изображений, у сети нет возможности прямо "запомнить" все изображения. И там такой датасет, что некоторые изображения довольно трудно однозначно опознать, вот на них сеть и ошибается. Т.е. это именно 0.23% изображений, которые нейросеть после тренировки на датасете (включая эти изображения) определяет неправильно. Ну, там, если посмотреть внимательно на её ошибки, и человек бы однозначно правильно бы не определил.

Вот эти 23 цифры, кстати, из той бумаги. Предположения нейросети вполне логичные. Правильная метка сверху, предположения нейросети (первое и второе по степени вероятности) снизу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]